# Deleting IMAP emails in bulk from Mac Mail

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, imap

I can delete single (or several) emails at a time in Mac Mail (Monterey) in my IMAP connected Gmail account.  They go to the Bin/Trash as expected and I will clear that up every once in a while.  All normal.

However, last night I deleted three sets of emails amounting to the thousands at a time.  After pressing delete a popup appeared asking me to make sure this is what I wanted.  I agreed, and they disappeared.  Though they didn't go to the Bin/Trash.  I didn't think this was too unusual as often when you delete large amounts they permanently delete straight away.  However, they were all still available in Gmail and my phone etc.  I thought that maybe for such a large deletion it would take time to be reflected on the Gmail site, but a day later they're all still there *and* they're now all re-downloading onto my computer!

This is unusual behaviour as far as I'm concerned.  I know I can delete normally in small quantities.  Does anyone have insight as to why this has happened?